# Swift adding VC from inside a closure not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, closures

So i'm trying to display a loading view when a user tap on a button. Below is the function

```
    /// Handles the shutter button tapped
    @objc func shutterTapped() {
        let parent = self.parent as! CameraActionViewController

        if parent.timerEngine.currentTime != 0 { parent.timerEngine.presentTimerDisplay() }
// This acts as a timer for the shutter to fire. (like a timer function for a camera)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(parent.timerEngine.currentTime)) {

            parent.cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletion({ result in
                switch result {
                case .failure:
                    AlertHelper.shared.presentDefault(title: "Error", message: "Looks like there was an error capturing the image.", to: self)

                case .success(let content):
                    let loadingVC = LoadingViewController()
                    parent.parent!.addVC(loadingVC)
                    print("processing...")

                    if let image = content.asImage {
                        guard let editedImage = FilterEngine.shared.process(originalImage: image) else {
                            TapticHelper.shared.errorTaptic()
                            return
                        }

                        guard let data = editedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) else {
                            TapticHelper.shared.errorTaptic()
                            return
                        }

                        DataEngine.shared.save(imageData: data)
                        print("Success")
                        TapticHelper.shared.successTaptic()
                        loadingVC.removeVC()
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

When the camera successfully captures the image and start to edit with all the filters selected by the user, I want to display the loading view. Because this is a heavy task and will freeze the UI for a second.

```
let loadingVC = LoadingViewController()
parent.parent!.addVC(loadingVC)
...
loadingVC.removeVC()
```

The method to add is here:

```
    func addVC(_ child: UIViewController) {
        addChild(child)
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func removeVC() {
        guard parent != nil else { return }

        willMove(toParent: nil)
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        removeFromParent()
    }
```

But for some reason, it is not showing the view at all. I then found out that it is somehow executed after the `DataEngine.shared.save(imageData: data)` line (adding to VC). Therefore since it is adding and removing at the same time, it shows nothing.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Dispatch all UI related tasks to the main queue. Try:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    parent.parent!.addVC(loadingVC)
}
```

And:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    loadingVC.removeVC()
}
```

Or simply put everything in the main queue right after the background task is complete:

```
parent.cameraManager.capturePictureWithCompletion({ result in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Still not working - I removed `loadingVC.removeVC()` just to see if it's actually adding to the view, and it's still not working. (View still added after all is completed and not before where it supposed to)

Comment: In that case it should be an issue with the functions remove and add did you try these out somewhere apart from this async task block?

Comment: Yes, for example, Adding the function via a button tap (without any other code, just adding) works flawlessly. Or, if i put the add function outside the async task block. But that wont be ideal because it shows the loading before the camera actually takes the picture.

Comment: Did you try it in the order you're doing here? presentTimerDisplay -> timer delay -> addVC -> removeVC? Do all the steps apart from sync task which is `capturePictureWithCompletion`.

Comment: Yes, I tried commenting the sync task and it's working. So i'd assume it's something to do inside the block.

Comment: Okay weird thing, it works by itself. I put the add method just before the switch (which is inside `DispatchQueue.main.async` and it fires it. Removing it simply have it on the same place. I'll mark your answer as correct since your answer leads to it behave as what i intended it